# invalid email [python] [DKIM signature]

Tags: python, email, mime, smtplib, dkim

I'm developing an email service in Python and using the dkimpy library to sign emails with DKIM. However, I'm encountering an issue where the generated DKIM signature is being reported as invalid during verification. (even without any MTA's modification)

**ERROR**

```
DKIM : Fail

the DKIM-Signature is invalid
Dns record: [v=DKIM1;t=s;p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDfuj1kWfsde62XeXRZFgpL3SNS8GaTSQknO9TspTFKOWyIqseNpzWuhv8zksEJ3fY8WYLnd/6Mww0qziPOO/pOcVzR9RCejunnzunWB5Bn/8yOkYEVkzgnWjxVxhULCQzTXG5UCB/83R9B4SRPU1J/rKZ3Ks45+WcB8dRNV5jmRwIDAQAB]
Domain: DOMAIN.TLD
Selector: SELECTOR
```

I have checked the following:

1. DNS configuration is correct: I have added the appropriate DKIM record for my domain and DKIM selector.
2. Public and private keys are correct: I have generated a DKIM key pair and I am using the private key for signing.
3. Using a simpler mail

Despite these checks, the DKIM signature is still being reported as invalid. I am using the following code snippet for signing the email:

```py
# Code snippet for signing the email using dkimpy library
import dkim

def signMail(mail):
    headers = ["To", "From", "Subject"]
    sig = dkim.sign(
        message=mail.as_bytes(),
        selector="SELECTOR".encode(),
        domain="DOMAIN.tld".encode(),
        privkey=self.private.encode(),
        include_headers=headers,
    )
    mail["DKIM-Signature"] = sig[len("DKIM-Signature: "):].decode()
```

**SIMPLE MAIL**

```
def sendTest(self,target):
        self.mail_tests = MIMEText("YO")
        self.mail_tests['Subject'] = "TEST"
        self.mail_tests['From'] = "NAME <"+self.address+">"
        self.mail_tests['Message-ID'] = email.utils.make_msgid(domain='DOMAIN.TLD')
        self.signMail(self.mail_tests)

        self.mail_tests['To'] = target

        self.sendMail(self.mail_tests.as_string(), target)
```

**SEND MAIL**

```
def sendMail(self, content, target):
        try:
            self.smtp.sendmail(self.address, target, content)
            print("sended",content)
        except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
            print(f"Error sending a mail : {e}")
```

**RESULT**

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: TEST
From: XYZ <noreply.xyz@DOMAIN.TLD>
Message-ID: <168675182014.460010.13148416338458835878@DOMAIN.TLD>
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=DOMAIN.TLD;
 i=@DOMAIN.TLD; q=dns/txt; s=SELECTOR; t=1686751820;
 h=to : from : subject;
 bh=L/kawiOJ5bUdFUXzv2TkE2CPohtcOrG6y7e1I+GpMG4=;
 b=dqucr/wyPLsdqhOLfMUhYFkscwdnQzkuMe9nkIV72PfLN7BobzXt7ndmsBEhfLNFbFb/m
 FhMYN9IGxGGgyntjwTROVLMkk5ew6+f3awS4m9Dsz9FB3N/U59QTUuQsMXL3Bi7cNTRx3gE
 8YdSt442E0MXOvzI0ikCH2WBIr1P78w=
To: test6116@wyz.com


YO
```

Comment: In your function `sendTest(self,target)` you call the `self.signMail(self.mail_tests)` function before adding `target` as the `To` property. Is this on purpose? It would result in the signature in the email covering only the `subject` and `from` headers, while suggesting also the `to` should be part of the signature. I'm not a developer by trade, so I could be mistaken.

Comment: Did I really did thata mistake ? Yes. Am I ashamed ? Yes. 
You are my savior !

Answer (score 0):

Solved by Reinto

```
def sendTest(self,target):
        self.mail_tests = MIMEText("YO")
        self.mail_tests['Subject'] = "TEST"
        self.mail_tests['From'] = "NAME <"+self.address+">"
        self.mail_tests['Message-ID'] = email.utils.make_msgid(domain='DOMAIN.TLD')
        self.mail_tests['To'] = target
        self.signMail(self.mail_tests)

        self.sendMail(self.mail_tests.as_string(), target)
```